# Can you use LDAP and PAM to implement a restricted shell?

Tags: linux, unix, ldap, pam

Can you use LDAP and PAM to implement a restricted shell and control those users via groups on the LDAP DC?

I would like to do this for several Red Hat, Solaris and Ubuntu servers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very short answer is yes. However, your question is rather broad and answering it in full is outside the scope of this site.

The general outline is to use `nss-ldap` to pull `posixGroups` via LDAP and have `sshd` use those groups as the condition for a `Match` block with a `ForcedCommand` directive.